# Column header in XTS and Data frame in R

Tags: machine-learning, r, data-science-model

I used  quandl function extract stock data with object type as `xts`.

```
a <- Quandl("NSE/ICICIBANK", start_date = "2011-01-01", end_date = "2019-02-21", collapse = "daily", type = "xts",order = "asc")
```

then I printed the output a with `head(a)`,
the output is

```
             Open    High     Low    Last   Close Total Trade Quantity Turnover (Lacs)
2011-01-03 1154.00 1158.40 1138.95 1140.35 1144.85              1379646        15845.58
2011-01-04 1145.70 1149.20 1098.10 1107.25 1104.05              4175490        46519.73
2011-01-05 1097.20 1099.00 1065.00 1068.80 1069.35              5307600        57075.28
2011-01-06 1074.25 1078.45 1047.25 1050.00 1053.45              4769781        50447.94
2011-01-07 1045.00 1077.90 1041.00 1042.00 1049.20              6178882        65700.46
2011-01-10 1044.25 1058.85 1005.10 1012.05 1014.00              6510410        67029.00
```

then I did the same without the object type as `xts`,
the output of `head(a)`:

```
       Date    Open    High     Low    Last   Close Total Trade Quantity Turnover (Lacs)
1 2011-01-03 1154.00 1158.40 1138.95 1140.35 1144.85              1379646        15845.58
2 2011-01-04 1145.70 1149.20 1098.10 1107.25 1104.05              4175490        46519.73
3 2011-01-05 1097.20 1099.00 1065.00 1068.80 1069.35              5307600        57075.28
4 2011-01-06 1074.25 1078.45 1047.25 1050.00 1053.45              4769781        50447.94
5 2011-01-07 1045.00 1077.90 1041.00 1042.00 1049.20              6178882        65700.46
6 2011-01-10 1044.25 1058.85 1005.10 1012.05 1014.00              6510410        67029.00
```

Why the date column field heading is missed out in `xts` object type but in data frame date field column heading is appearing?
How to handle the same in `xts` object type?

Answer (score 1):

Because an R xts object stores the date-column in a special column called `index`, and the programmers who implemented the  xts package have decided  to not print a label such as "Date" in the table header of an xts output.

When the `print()` method is called with an xts object as argument, the first column of the output is actually printed without any label, like a rowname "column" of a data frame.

Why? I don't know. Perhaps "Date" is not always right. It could just be a different label that your time series needs (e.g. "Microseconds" for some timeseries object of Sensor measurements)

```
# returned as data frame by Quandl
 R> str(a)

    'data.frame':   1985 obs. of  8 variables:
     $ Date                : Date, format: "2011-01-03" "2011-01-04" "2011-01-05" "2011-01-06" ...
     $ Open                : num  1154 1146 1097 1074 1045 ...
     $ High                : num  1158 1149 1099 1078 1078 ...
     $ Low                 : num  1139 1098 1065 1047 1041 ...
     $ Last                : num  1140 1107 1069 1050 1042 ...
     $ Close               : num  1145 1104 1069 1053 1049 ...
     $ Total Trade Quantity: num  1379646 4175490 5307600 4769781 6178882 ...
     $ Turnover (Lacs)     : num  15846 46520 57075 50448 65700 ...
     - attr(*, "freq")= chr "daily"

# returned as xts timeseries object

    R> str(ax)
    An ‘xts’ object on 2011-01-03/2019-01-04 containing:
      Data: num [1:1985, 1:7] 1154 1146 1097 1074 1045 ...
     - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
      ..$ : NULL
      ..$ : chr [1:7] "Open" "High" "Low" "Last" ...
      Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
      xts Attributes:  
     NULL
```